# Using Laravel/Eloquent to create a list of items grouped by a related model's column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a table called **celebrities** that has a many-to-many relationship to three other tables: **collections**, **categories**, and **tags**. I currently have my API set up to return the following:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "display_name": "Joe Shmo",
        "born": "1917-05-11",
        "died": null,
        "biography": "Some guy in a well-known TV show.",
        "collections": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Featured Celebrity"
            }
        ],
        "categories": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Movies/TV"
            }
        ],
        "tags": []
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "display_name": "Jane Doe",
        "born": "1914-05-11",
        "died": "1993-10-30",
        "biography": "She was famous for a show in the 80's.",
        "collections": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Top Ten Celebrities"
            }
        ],
        "categories": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Movies/TV"
            }
        ],
        "tags": []
    },
...
```

I'd like to return the JSON grouped by the **name** value from **collections**. Here's an example of what I want:

```
[
    {
        "Feature Celebrity": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "display_name": "Joe Shmo",
                "born": "1917-05-11",
                "died": null,
                "biography": "Some guy in a well-known TV show.",
                "categories": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "Movies/TV"
                    }
                ],
                "tags": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Top Ten Celebrities": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "display_name": "Jane Doe",
                "born": "1993-05-11",
                "died": null,
                "biography": "A famouse beach volley ball person.",
                "categories": [
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "Sports"
                    }
                ],
                "tags": []
            },
            ...
        ]
    }
]
```

As for my Laravel code, here is what I have setup.

**Celebrity (model)**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Celebrity extends Model
{
    protected $hidden = ['pivot'];

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
    }

    public function collections()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Collection');
    }

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag');
    }
}
```

**Collection (model)**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Collection extends Model
{
    protected $hidden = ['pivot'];

    public function celebrities()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Celebrity');
    }
}
```

**Category (model)**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    protected $hidden = ['pivot'];
}
```

**Tag (model)**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tag extends Model
{
    protected $hidden = ['pivot'];
}
```

In my **CelebrityController** I have the following code that returns JSON in the format like I show in the first example:

```
public function list($born = null) {
        if (!isset($born)) {
            $born = date('m-d');
        }

        return Celebrity::with([
            'collections:id,name',
            'categories:id,name',
            'tags:id,name',
        ])
            ->where('born', 'like', '%-' . $born . '%')
            ->get([
                'id',
                'display_name',
                'born',
                'died',
                'biography',
            ]);
    }
```

Here is an image of my tables and their relationships:
[Celebrity Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yS5IG.png)

I'm very new to Laravel and Eloquent. I can't figure out how to get from the first JSON example to the second. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What happens if a celebrity has more than one collection? Show in both?

Comment: Did you check [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-groupby)? Using Eloquent's `get()` method returns a collection.